# Private messaging gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, message

Is there a good app for private messages, similar to LinkedIn (i.e. send to other users you are connected to)?

I've seen mailboxes and simple-private-messages...but am wondering if there are any other good ones, or secure apis

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For these kinds of questions, I am a huge fan of [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/User_Messaging_Systems). It's a great site for these kinds of things. According to that, [Mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer) is the most popular, [rails-messaging](https://github.com/frodefi/rails-messaging) the second, and [acts-as-messageable](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable) is the third.